# Filepond : Return json data from php call

Tags: php, json, filepond

I would like to return json data from my php call with this code :

```
    pond.on('processfiles', (error, file) => {
    if (error) {
        //console.log('Oh no');
        Swal.fire({
          icon: 'error',
          title: 'Oops...',
          text: 'Oh no',
          backdrop: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#437A25",
        }); 
        return;
    }
        pond.removeFiles();

        Swal.fire({
          icon: 'success',
          title: 'Merci !',
          text: 'Message returned by JSON here ?',
          backdrop: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#437A25",
        }); 
});
```

and here is the json string returned from the php :

```
        header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK'); 
        $msg = array('success' => 'true', 'msg' => 'Thanks to you Jim !', 'extra' => '');
        echo json_encode($msg); exit;
```

How can I get msg value to show in the console.log ?

Thanks for your help...